# Are the first 128 characters of utf-8 and ascii identical?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, ascii

Are the first 128 characters of utf-8 and ascii identical?

[utf-8 table](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl)

[Ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: The first 128 code points are the same, yes. Note that they aren’t all characters.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen What would you call the oens that aren't characters? Commands?

Comment: I may have misspoken, seems they do use the term character also for control, formatting etc symbols.

Comment: Maybe you are comparing clementines with tangerines. UTF-8 is a character encoding for the Unicode character set. ASCII is a character set with one character encoding (or two, if you count the one that is 8 bits with high bit zero as different than the one that is 7 bits with high bit used for anything else, like parity). "First characters" implies something like codepoints (input) rather than code units (output) or bytes (serialized code units) but "character" is a loosely defined term.

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/395119)? Do you have a library that can read UTF-8 but not ASCII but want to apply it to data that is ASCII? Otherwise, just use the character encoding that is agreed upon or communicated between writer and reader.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen If any are called characters, I would call them all characters. From the UTF-8 perspective, they are the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block Unicode codepoints.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This was an intentional choice in the design of UTF-8 so that existing 7-bit ASCII would be compatible.

The encoding is also designed intentionally so that 7-bit ASCII values cannot mean anything *except* their ASCII equivalent. For example, in UTF-16, the Euro symbol (€) is encoded as 0x20 0xAC. But 0x20 is SPACE in ASCII. So if an ASCII-only algorithm tries to space-delimit a string like "€ 10" encoded in  UTF-16, it'll corrupt the data.

This can't happen in UTF-8. € is encoded there as 0xE2 0x82 0xAC, none of which are legal 7-bit ASCII values. So an ASCII algorithm that naively splits on the ASCII SPACE (0x20) will still work, even though it doesn't know anything about UTF-8 encoding. (The same is true for any ASCII character like slash, comma, backslash, percent, etc.) UTF-8 is an incredibly clever text encoding.